# How is 名 pronounced in computer terms?

Tags: kanji, readings, terminology, computing

For usernames, etc., you usually see like `ユーザ名` or something similar.  Or like on my Skype, it says `Skype名`.  How is the 名 pronounced in these situations?  I've never been able to conclusively find this anywhere.  My instinct tells me it's `な` because these seem like compounds nouns (like `星空【ほしぞら】`, etc.) that use kun-yomi.

Comment: I have seen this mysterious single-word sentence “Topic.” at the beginning of some of your questions.  What does it mean?

Comment: It means the main question I want to ask is in the title itself, so I don't want to repeat it in the body of the post (even though I did in this one anyway.  Oops).

Comment: I see, but I think that you can omit it and it will make the question easier to read.

Comment: Yeah, I guess really you'd only use it if you had nothing else to add in the body.

Comment: It's interesting though how in Japanese you don't have to verbalise while reading kanji. E.g., in 「Skype名」 you just _see_ ‘name’—no need to think how exactly to pronounce 名 (unless you have to say it out loud). I think it's cool—you quicker get to the meaning, skipping unnecessary reading. On the other hand, it's probably since I'm just a beginner and don't know how to pronounce things. =) I'm curious whether native speakers usually verbalise written kanji or not… Although I guess it's not easy to find out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is read as めい.  “ユーザ名” is read as ユーザめい, “Skype 名” is スカイプめい.

I do not know the reason for that, but if I make a guess, this may be because gairaigo in a compound word is treated in a similar way to [Sino-Japanese words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sino-Japanese_vocabulary).

Comment: Yes, here is the example itself in [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gairaigo#Grammatical_function) (however much trust one assigns to Wikipedia).

Comment: After thinking about it a little bit, reading “Skype 名” as スカイプな seems cooler than スカイプめい (probably because I am too sleepy now).