# クラウド上で - pronunciation?

Tags: readings, suffixes

I've seen 上で quite a few times recently, in contexts like:

> In the cloud
>
> クラウド上で

and：

> On the computer
>
> コンピュータ上

In this case, is it pronounced うえ, as in クラウドうえで, or じょう?

Silly little question, but none of the tools I have (rikaichan etc) help me to find the answer. If there's a better way I could have found the answer, please let me know!

Comment: In the case of the first example, I would assume it was the grammer construction 上で（じょうで）, meaning on/in. Although there are quite a few grammer constructions consisting of noun + 上（上、上に、上は、上で） so depending on the context of the sentence its possible it could be different.

Comment: Related: [How is 名 pronounced in computer terms?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3703/how-is-%E5%90%8D-pronounced-in-computer-terms)

Comment: Also related: [JLPT N1 question: Why isn't a large amount of money a good enough reason to kill someone?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3174/78) and [What does it mean to be “over a law”?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4329/78).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is pronounced じょう in both cases.