# How to read 連体形 + 上

Tags: grammar, kanji, readings

Taking an example from a [page](http://www.nhk.or.jp/bunken/summary/kotoba/uraomote/111.html) naruto linked in another thread:

> 外国人が日本語を習得する**上**で難しい点がたくさんあります。

My inclination is to read this as うえ since it's followed by で, however I've got a nagging feeling it might be read as じょう instead.

- Is my instinct correct in that it's read as うえ?
- Are there times where 連体形 + じょう is the appropriate way to read it?

Comment: I may be wrong, but isn't this the 連体形?

Comment: @snailboat Expert opinion?

Comment: Um, I don't claim to be an expert :-)  But since you asked I can comment anyway.  I would call it the 連体形 rather than 終止形 because it's adnominalized to a noun, but since 連体形・終止形 have merged for verbs, it doesn't seem like an important distinction to me.

Comment: I'd consider it 連体形 as well. But as @snailboat notes, it hardly matters for verbs anymore. But consider the 形容動詞 for which the distinction may still be noted. ～なる上.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is read `ウエ` as you were inclined to think.  I do not believe there are any times when it would be read as `ジョウ` after a dictionary form.  It ***is*** read as `ジョウ` when appearing directly after a noun.

See also

- [クラウド上で - pronunciation?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6495/78)
- [What does it mean to be “over a law”?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4329/78)

Comment: Ah, noun + 上 may have been what was causing my confusion then.  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I'm not familiar with the term "dictionary form". So クラウド is not a dictionary form?

Comment: @dainichi By "dictionary form" I'm referring to how you would look the word up in the dictionary.  Since Japanese nouns are fairly stable in nature, it's usually used to refer to 終止形 verbs, and occasionally to い-adjectives (not sure of the name for the base form there).

Comment: @dainichi Material for Japanese learners frequently uses the term "dictionary form" (or 辞書形) to refer to the 終止形・連体形 of verbs, since that is their citation form in dictionaries. See, e.g. http://www.jpfmw.ru/assets/files/Nihongo_kyozai/How%20to%20teach%20dic%20form.pdf or, I imagine, any introductory textbook for English-speaking Japanese learners.