# How is 上 used in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, usage

I have trouble understanding what 上 means in this sentence.

> これからの人生を送る**上**でとても豊かな経験ができたことは一生の宝物！

If I had to interpret これからの人生を送る上で, it means "within my life from now on"? and is the で particle is used to indicate scope of this person's life?

Can someone explain how 上 works here?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34125/9831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually not just 上, it's the grammar pattern「Aする上で」. 「Aする上で」means something like "When doing A". 
So your sentence means something like "The fact that I have had a very rich experience will be very beneficial (a lifetime treasure?) for my future life!"
Though the lack of context makes this sentence a bit weird.

Here are some example sentences from yourei.jp :

そのため、英語が苦手だと、実験を**作成するうえで**の自由度が制限される。
Therefore, if you're bad at English, the degree of freedom **in creating experiments (when creating experiments)** will be limited.

これまた西欧文明を**理解するうえで**、忘れてはならないことでありましょう。
Again, let's not forget this **when trying to understand** Western European civilization.

基本的に動物福祉を**説明するうえで**以下の3つの概念が用いられる。
Basically, the following three concepts are used to explain **(when explaining)** animal welfare.

もちろん、脳は世界を**認識するうえで**の「ハブ」となる大切な臓器です。
Of course, the brain is an important organ that becomes a "hub" **in percepting (when percepting)** the world.

As you can see する上で can also be followed by の if there's a noun after it.

Comment: I love the examples, much appreciated! Can I interpret the sentence like this? "It is a lifetime treasure in (when living) my life from now on that I was a able to have very rich experiences." The context is basically like a person returning from some overseas study experience.

Comment: Well, yes, I suppose that'll do. You could probably come up with a more natural translation but that's up to you.